# How to convert binary to ascii in assembly

Tags: assembly, text, binary, ascii

Im new to assembly language, i can have an idea in how to convert binary to ascii in another language but im having a hard time with assembly (assembly IA32, intel in linux).

The user must put a string of binary and the lenght like:  01100001011101000110000101110001011101010110010101101110  56

and the ouput must be:  ataquen

Im not asking to give me the complete function but i would like to know if there are some tips in assembly than can help me to build my program. Thanks.

Comment: Which platform Mac, Linux, Windows? Which processor AVR, ARM, Intel, MIPS, etc? Which assembler YASM, NASM, MASM, GAS? 64 / 32 bit?

Comment: IA32 with linux

Comment: Binary to decimal/etc are not needed. A value is a value, binary/decimal is formatting of value, not value itself. So in assembler if you have register `al` equal to 38, it means it contains `38` in decimal, `100110` in binary and `26` in hexadecimal, all of them at the same time, as those are just representation of the value, which is in `al`. But your input is not binary value, it's string. So it's stream of `0x30` (`'0'`) and `0x31` (`'1'`) values, which have to be converted by group of 8 of them into single value. (like for two chars: value = 2^1*(char1-'0') + 2^0*(char2-'0') => "11" = 3).

Comment: And that value `38` is also equal to ASCII character `'&'` ... again ASCII is just formatting of value. So once you calculate the value from the stream of 0/1 ascii letters, if you end with value `65` for example, and output it by some function as ASCII character, it will show as `A`. If you output it as number by other function, it will show as 65.  (if you want to show value 65 on screen as binary, then you need binary formatter function, which will create the "01000001" string into some buffer, and display it = CPU has no such direct instruction of course, that's too complex, same for dec).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ESI points to users input and ECX = 8, this will convert a string of eight ASCII "0" & "1".

```
 NextCh:
        lodsb           
        ror     al, 1
        rcl     ah, 1
        loop    NextCh
```

So if input was `01110011` then AH is 0b1110011 = 73H = 115 = 's'

Answer (score 0):

Each Ascii char is made up of one byte (8 bits). Each of your characters is either a 30h or a 31h (0 or 1). Read 8 of them. Calculate what number they are. Output as char.

Comment: but does assembly have a function to transform binary to decimal, and decimal to char?